# Running an ARFaceTrackingConfiguration after updating to Swift 5 and iOS 12.2 SDK causes the session to run very slowly

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a UIButton which the user taps and it takes them to a view controller which has its root view as a ARSCNView, however doing so before worked perfectly and was really fast (~1s), but now it takes a few seconds (~8s) for the controller to show up and run the ARFaceTrackingConfiguration session.

TLDR; This code here ran the session in ~1s but in Swift 5 it runs it at ~8s.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     arSceneView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration(), options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

I also get a warning that the UI API must be called from the main thread.

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 31934, TID: 5427839, Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now in debug mode it takes a much longer than it originally did, opening the app without running it from Xcode does "fix" it. This wasn't the case pre-12.2 SDK.